# Django 2.2.4 unable to serve my static files

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

In my application I was unable to serve static files like images and js.

Looks like everything is correct but still I am unable to figure out why it is not loading.

I have tried few options in stackoverflow none of them worked for me.

Settings.py

```
STATICFILES_DIR = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My project structure

```
mydjangonginx
    |-mydjango_app
         | -urls.py
         | -views.py
         | -...
    |-mydjangonginx
         | -urls.py
         | -settings.py
         | -...
    |-static
         | -images
              | -login.jpg
         | -js
              | -my.js
```

mydjango_app/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
          path('login', views.login, name='login'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

mydjangonginx/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('myapp/', include('mydjango_app.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

login.html

```
<html>
    {% load static %}
    login
    <script src="{% static 'js/my.js' %}"></script>
    <img src="{% static 'images/login.jpg' %}" />
</html>
```

both the js and images are not loading

can anyone help on this

Comment: Your `settings.py` is inside `mydjangonginx` so I think that it looks for `static` folder inside `mydjangonginx`

Comment: What is you BASE_DIR set to?

Comment: it was set to C:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\django\bin\mydjangonginx @NicoGriffioen

Comment: even if i keep the static folder inside mydjangonginx , it is not working @KostasCharitidis

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

The static folder should be next to `manage.py` in the same folder (this is `BASE_DIR` if you did not change it).

`'django.contrib.staticfiles'` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? And you are using the `{% static 'folder/some.file' %}` template tag to serve the static files?

Also note that adding staticfiles to the urlpatterns is not needed when running in `DEBUG` mode.

Edit: it has to be `STATICFILES_DIRS` not `STATICFILES_DIR`

Comment: adding to this answer, there is also a command to find the static files in django through `manage.py`, it can be found here: (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#findstatic)